# Flot chart time xaxis series is off

Tags: jquery, flot

The following flot chart [example](http://www.jqueryflottutorial.com/how-to-make-jquery-flot-line-chart.html) uses a time series and data for 12 months.  Notice how the first element in the series (month #1) is plotted along the x-axis and does not have the correct label (it's blank).  The second data value (month #2) is incorrectly labeled January, etc.  The data format is provided in the link above, but a quick cut/paste below:

> var data1 = [
>       [gd(2012, 0, 1), 1652.21], [gd(2012, 1, 1), 1742.14], [gd(2012, 2, 1), 1673.77], [gd(2012, 3, 1), 1649.69],
>       [gd(2012, 4, 1), 1591.19], [gd(2012, 5, 1), 1598.76], [gd(2012, 6, 1), 1589.90], [gd(2012, 7, 1), 1630.31],
>       [gd(2012, 8, 1), 1744.81], [gd(2012, 9, 1), 1746.58], [gd(2012, 10, 1), 1721.64], [gd(2012, 11, 1), 1684.76] ];

How should I change this so that the 12 data elements are correctly labeled from January - December, instead of Blank - November?

[image: example of time series issue]

Comment: I am using my psychic abilities and predict: The first timestamp is 2011-12-31 22:00 UTC or similar, the second 2012-01-31 22:00 UTC and so on. Can you please show your data (atleast the first few timestamps)?

Comment: correct, I edited my post but the link includes the full dataset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the correct x-axis labels by changing the `gd` function to this:

```
function gd(year, month, day) {
    return new Date(year, month + 1, day, -5).getTime();
}
```

The `-5` subtracts my timezone offset. I am not sure why adding one to the month was necessary.

[image: Flot Line Chart with Correct X-Axis Lables]

Comment: Thank you, I just shed a small tear of joy!